# Is it mandatory to have keyusage in certificate if using jdk7

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am using jdk1.7.
i am using self signed certificates for SSL handshake.
is it mandatory to have keyusage in certificate if i am using jdk1.7.
Please let me know i am confused.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Do you have a reason for not wanting to include the keyusage extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-29) says:

> Conforming CAs MUST include this extension in certificates that
> contain public keys that are used to validate digital signatures on
> other public key certificates or CRLs.  When present, conforming CAs
> SHOULD mark this extension as critical.

However, [RFC 6818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6818), which is an update to RFC 5280, says:

> Consistent with Section 3.4.61 of X.509 (11/2008) [X.509], we note
> that use of self-issued certificates and self-signed certificates
> issued by entities other than CAs are outside the scope of this
> specification.  Thus, for example, a web server or client might
> generate a self-signed certificate to identify itself.  These
> certificates and how a relying party uses them to authenticate
> asserted identities are both outside the scope of RFC 5280.

So, if you're acting in the capacity of a CA, you should include keyusage.  It's probably a good idea to include it anyway, although it isn't strictly required based on the paragraph above.